# How to return the results of a MongoDB cursor back to Actix-web for display?

Tags: mongodb, rust, actix-web

I'm using Actix-web 4.0.0.rc3 along with MongoDB 2.1.0 (async mode).  I've got the db integrated with Actix via app_data, but I'm trying to figure out how to display the results of a multi-document cursor.

Currently I'm using:

```
while let Some(doc) = cursor.try_next().await? {
  // processing doc results, and building a row of data
}
```

Spitting out the results is easy, but I can't figure out how to get those results to display in the browser.  I've been searching for an example that would explain how to do this, but haven't found a solution thus far.  Using handlebars it was easy to get a field from the DB, and display those results, but the cursor of unknown size has my stumped.  I've done this easily with RoR, or Phoenix/Elixir - would appreciate any suggestions (or just a gentle nudge to an example that might already exist).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have that example:

```rs
pub async fn get_aggregation_as_json_response(
    db: &Database,
    aggr_pipeline: Vec<Document>,
) -> HttpResponse {
    let mut cursor = db
        .collection_with_type::<ExampleModel>("examplemodel")
        .aggregate(aggr_pipeline, None)
        .await
        .expect("Error performing aggregation on examplemodel  collection.");

    let mut results: Vec<Document> = Vec::new();

    while let Some(result) = cursor.next().await {
        match result {
            Ok(document) => {
                results.push(document);
            }
            Err(_) => {
                return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish();
            }
        }
    }

    HttpResponse::Ok().json(results)
}
```

Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.

I had something like this, but it returns the entire document (unless we use a projection on the results).  Some of these documents are large, and I didn't want to return a lot of data.  Hence I was creating a format! string, which printlin! would've spit out.  Ideally I'll want this in a proper table eventually.

Comment: With an aggregation you can use a $project key to select only the fields you want. This doesn't work for you ?

Comment: The issue isn’t the db at all.   I don’t want to be dumping json data back to the browser.   Ideally I want to mark up the resulting cursor into a nicely formatted table.  Like you, I used a vec of type String (instead of Document) as I had formatted the resulting row.    Not sure how to iterate over that Vec to pass it back to HttpResponse::Ok(). Using .json isn’t what I want, and .body isn’t working out the way I intended either.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what exactely you want to return. Is it like an html document calculated with the data ?

Comment: Yes, essentially.   I already had a version of HttpResponse::Ok().json(results) working, as you suggested.  That just returns the json documents to the browser, which isn't formatted.  I'd like the result of the query to be in an HTML table.  I've tried formatting a Vec<String> with html data representing the rows, and I can spit that out with  HttpResponse::Ok().json(results) but it also then doesn't handle the formatting, as it is expecting json.  I'm just not sure what the correct process is to iterate over a Vec  (as an example), to spit out a table in Actix.

Comment: Ok, so could you share what you have tried so far to build the string ? It could be a starting point to think about it.

Comment: I had a `let mut results: Vec<String> = Vec::new();` and in the iterator for the cursor, I had `results.push(format!("format string here"));`  I'm not sure how to spit out `results` via an HttpResponse, or something like that in Actix.

Comment: You could use string concatenation with `String::push_str(&str)` instead of pushing in an Vec of strings ? That way you'd have just one string and you could return it in the `body()` of the response.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that gets me a lot closer.